# How to store "complex" variable in environment?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have two stages and I want to share the info object with their properties to the second stage

```
    stage("Enter deploy information") 
    {
        options 
        {
            timeout(time: 3, unit: 'MINUTES') 
        }
        steps 
        {
            script 
            {
                env.info = askForDeployInformation()
            }
        }
    }

    stage('Get artifact')
    {
        steps
        {
            customCopyArtifacts(env.info.BranchName, env.info.BuildNumber)
        }
    }
```

But this fails with this error:

```
 org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such field found: field java.lang.String BranchName
11:56:44    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.unclassifiedField(SandboxInterceptor.java:425)
11:56:44    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:409)
11:56:44    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:353)
11:56:44    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:357)
11:56:44    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
11:56:44    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
11:56:44    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:24)
11:56:44    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.delegateAndExecute(ModelInterpreter.groovy:137)
```

How to store "complex" variable in environment?

Comment: Why not simply use `${BUILD_NUMBER}` and `${BRANCH_NAME}`? Aren't they available by default?

Comment: Because I ask the user for the branch and the build number, strange requirements but that's what we need. In addition, this is the deploy job, the build job is another one with multibranch.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store complex objects in the environment variables. This goes for all the operating systems I know of. Only strings can be stored there. You can assign numbers or booleans:

```
env.VAR_1 = 12
env.VAR_2 = true
```

But these will anyhow be converted to strings (`"12"` and `"true"` respectively).

Comment: Then how can I access the info object in the other stage? Currently im saving its properties to env.BranchName, env.BuildNumber and accesing this way.